QueryDSL with JPA inheritance (SingleTable) causes problems
I currently have a small problem when creating a query with QueryDSL. There is an entity of the type Person. This has one or more supervisors. The supervisors can be of type Superior or Manager. A manager is always stronger than a superior. Both types are stored in the Supervisor table & are differentiated via DiscriminatorValue.
I would now like to achieve the following:

Return people who have the requester as a manager
Return people who have the requester as their superior if there is no manager

My BooleanExpression for this looks like this:
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
QPerson qPerson = QPerson.person;
        
BooleanExpression isManager = qPerson.managers.any().supervisor.id.eq(supervisorId);
BooleanExpression isSuperior = qPerson.managers.any().isNull().and(qPerson.superiors.any().supervisor.id.eq(supervisorId));
builder.andAnyOf(isManager, isSuperior);

Problem: if I only use one of the two elements, the discriminator is selected correctly:
select p1_0.id from person p1_0 where exists(select 1 from (select * from base_supervisor t where t.supervisor_type='Manager') m1_0 where m1_0.supervisor_id=? and p1_0.id=m1_0.subordinate_id)
select p1_0.id from person p1_0 where exists(select 1 from (select * from base_supervisor t where t.supervisor_type='Manager') m1_0 where m1_0.id is null and p1_0.id=m1_0.subordinate_id) and exists(select 1 from (select * from base_supervisor t where t.supervisor_type='Superior') s1_0 where s1_0.supervisor_id=? and p1_0.id=s1_0.subordinate_id)
However, as soon as I combine the two, this is ignored, which leads to incorrect results.
select p1_0.id from person p1_0 where exists(select 1 from base_supervisor m1_0 where m1_0.supervisor_id=? and p1_0.id=m1_0.subordinate_id) or exists(select 1 from base_supervisor m2_0 where m2_0.id is null and p1_0.id=m2_0.subordinate_id) and exists(select 1 from base_supervisor s2_0 where s2_0.supervisor_id=? and p1_0.id=s2_0.subordinate_id)
I have created the repo to recreate the problem: click
I am very happy to receive answers and possible solutions.

By using JPQLQuery I was at least able to get the query to run correctly. The Code:
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
QPerson qPerson = QPerson.person;

QManager qManager = QManager.manager;
QSuperior qSuperior = QSuperior.superior;

JPQLQuery<String> pManager = JPAExpressions.select(qManager.supervisor.id).from(qManager).where(qManager.subordinate.eq(qPerson));
JPQLQuery<String> pSuperior = JPAExpressions.select(qSuperior.supervisor.id).from(qSuperior).where(qSuperior.subordinate.eq(qPerson));

BooleanExpression isManager = pManager.contains(supervisorId);
BooleanExpression isSuperior = pManager.isNull().and(pSuperior.contains(supervisorId));
builder.andAnyOf(isManager, isSuperior);

And the result:
select p1_0.id from person p1_0 where ? in (select m1_0.supervisor_id from base_supervisor m1_0 where m1_0.subordinate_id=p1_0.id and m1_0.supervisor_type='Manager') or (select m2_0.supervisor_id from base_supervisor m2_0 where m2_0.subordinate_id=p1_0.id and m2_0.supervisor_type='Manager') is null and ? in (select s5_0.supervisor_id from base_supervisor s5_0 where s5_0.subordinate_id=p1_0.id and s5_0.supervisor_type='Superior')
However, I am not yet sure whether the behaviour above is not possibly a bug in querydsl/hibernate. If I link the BooleanExpressions with and, then the discriminators are taken correctly. However, as soon as I use or, the discriminators fly out.
